# Visual Studio 2013 highlight stronger than Visual Assist X

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-assist, productivity-power-tools

There are 3 related highlight settings in Tools / Options / Environment / Fonts and Colors

- Highlighted reference (A)
- VA Find reference (B)
- VA Find reference (modified) (C)

If I move onto a variable with the cursor then all references become highlighted using (A). If I move away from that place to a neutral area (for example end of line after a semicolon) then the highlighted texts change colors to (B) and (C) correctly.

I would like to see (B) and (C) coloring while I am on the variable with the cursor.

I tried to turn on and off many things in Options and Visual Assist Options, but couldn't find any good combination. Searching the Internet hasn't helped (at least yet).

**UPDATE**

"Productivity Power Tools" came into play. I will post an answer for reference for other users in distress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Productivity power tools has a conflicting option group on the Tools / Options / Productivity Power Tools / Other extensions page, namely "Match margin options". It has two options (Show matches in the margin, Show matches in the editor). Both needs to be unchecked.

Comment: I would like to know how to configure the background color of "other extensions/match in editor".  I use a dark background and changing the "highlighted reference has no effect